Is a damaged print bed what is causing my prints to fail?
Yesterday, I had the worst print since getting my printer (Creality Ender 3 V3 SE). There was plastic all over the hotend, and I was left with a large clump as my print.
From what I understand, the problem is caused by printing in mid-air, so either my Z-offset is to blame or my print bed. I have attached photos of the bed, the line is smaller than 1 mm deep and there is a 3D Benchy I could print attached to show what it looks like. Could the print bed be causing the issues?




Hi, welcome to 3D Printing! Are the bed engravings and failing print from the same session? It is unlikely that these linear bed defects are the cause of failing prints, it looks like there are seperate issues at play here.

@0scar no, the engraving is from transporting the printer. I managed to get it to reprint successfully, so I think it was just a single time problem, thanks!

The print managed to print the second time, so this wasn’t the issue.

It's good that you found what was not the issue. If you do happen to find out what the issue actually was, please come back and [edit] your answer with the update. Thanks.

If first few layers printed OK, and are still attached to the bed, then the damage that you have indicated in your picture is unlikely to be the cause.
If the first few layers printed OK and the print had detached from the print bed, then there is a slight chance that the damage causes it to detach.
From the look of the underside of your model, there seems to be not tell tale witness marks that correspond to the damage, so it's unlikely to be the cause.
